# Taildwindcss dark mode toggle using javascript object

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, dom, browser-storage

I'm learning javascript objects and ES6 and made this dark mode toggle for TailwindCSS. I'd like to know what can I improve with this code below

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // App
    let app = {
        elements: {
            transitions: document.getElementsByClassName('transition transition-all transition'),
        },
        
        init: () => {
            app.darkMode.init();
        }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Dark Mode 
    app.darkMode =  {
        elements: { 
            toggles: document.getElementsByClassName('dark_mode_toggle'), 
        },

        init: () => {
            // Add click event to each dark mode elements
            for(let i = 0; i< app.darkMode.elements.toggles.length; i++){
                app.darkMode.elements.toggles[i].addEventListener("click", () => app.darkMode.toggle());
            }

            // Trigger dark mode changes
            app.darkMode.value() ? localStorage.theme = 'light' : localStorage.theme = 'dark';
            app.darkMode.value() ? document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark") : document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");

            // Add change event to monitor device's dark mode setting
            window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', event => app.darkMode.toggle());
        },

        value: () => {
            // Return theme value from local storage or device's dark mode setting as boolean
            if (localStorage.theme === 'light' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches)){        
                return true;
            }else if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
                return false;
            }
        },

        toggle: () => {
            // Handle transition classes
            for(let i = 0; i< app.elements.transitions.length; i++){
                app.elements.transitions[i].classList.add("transition-none");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    elements.transitions[i].classList.remove("transition-none");
                }, 1500);
            }

            // Execute dark mode change
            app.darkMode.value() ? localStorage.theme = 'dark' : localStorage.theme = 'light';
            app.darkMode.value() ? document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark") : document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
        },
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Initialize app
    app.init();
})
```